# How does let/var resolve mutability?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, immutability

I don't have any problem, i would just like some clarification on an issue regarding mutability.

In Objective-C we would use for example `NSMutableArray` to get a mutable array and an `NSArray` to get an immutable one. I don't know much about the inner workings of the two, but from what I can remember I believe that the difference is that `NSArray` only reserves an amount of memory specific to the initial value which makes it more efficient, while `NSMutableArray` has no idea how much memory it will require. Presumably this means that `NSMutableArray` has pointers to bits of memory that are all over the place and not one by one like with `NSArray`? Or does it perhaps just reserve a lot of memory hoping it won't run out?

In Swift the obvious substitution is `let` for immutable and `var` for mutable. If a variable is declared with these keywords that I see no difference between Swift and Objective-C. However, I don't understand how it works if I declare the variable without the var/let by, for example, storing it in another variable.

Let's say I have a dictionary such as `[String: [String]]`. In other words, for each string key there is an array of strings. Consider the following case:

```
var dictionary: [String: [String]] = [:]
dictionary["key"] = ["string0", "string1"]

//dictionary now is ["key": ["string0", "string1"]]
```

But what is the strings array now? Is it mutable because the dictionary is mutable? Is it mutable because everything we assign is mutable? How about the following case:

```
let dictionary = ["key": ["string0", "string1"]]
dictionary["key"].append("string2")
```

Would this work?

I guess the key issue is that in Objective-C I always define whether am I working with `NSMutableArray` or `NSArray`. Creating an array using the literal syntax `[@"string"]` always leads to an `NSArray` and it won't be mutable unless I specify it. In Swift I don't know when is what mutable.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays and dictionaries, the `let` or `var` keyword decides whether the whole collection would be mutable or immutable. In other words, if you declare a dictionary immutable by using the `let` keyword, you cannot change any of its values, so the second example would not work.

In `Swift` deciding whether a collection will be mutable or immutable only depends on the keyword you use to declare it, so declaring an array/dictionary using the `let` keyword will be equivalent to declaring an immutable array (`NSArray` in Objective-C) while declaring it with the `var` keyword will give you a mutable array (`NSMutableArray` in Objective-C).

Answer (score 1):

> If you create an array, a set, or a dictionary, and assign it to a
>   variable, the collection that is created will be mutable. This means
>   that you can change (or mutate) the collection after it is created by
>   adding, removing, or changing items in the collection. If you assign
>   an array, a set, or a dictionary to a constant, that collection is
>   immutable, and its size and contents cannot be changed.

So, `let` means constant, if you declare array or dictionary using `let` it will be immutable.

if you declare array or dictionary as `var` it will be mutable.

So, the case below will not work because dictionary will be immutable:

```
let dictionary = ["key": ["string0", "string1"]]
dictionary["key"].append("string2")
```

Check the reference here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html