# i'm trying to use a for..loop to describe the .endsWith() method

Tags: javascript

I'm basically trying to write a function which when called, performs the action of the endsWith() method

I've tried iterating through the original string and the string to be tested using for loops

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
  let strWord = '';
  let targetWord = '';
  for (let i = (target.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    targetWord.concat(target.charAt(i))
    for (let j = (str.length - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
      strWord.concat(str.charAt(j));

    }
  }
  if (strWord == targetWord) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Now anytime i call the function, it returns true, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: strings are immutable. So, `targetWord.concat` doesn't change the original string

Comment: [String.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) like other string methods returns a new string it doesnt modify the original string

Answer (score 0):

Primarily, what's wrong with it is that you're using nested loops. There's no need to do that.

The simple, easy way (other than using `endsWith`!) is to grab the end of `str` (using the length of `target`), then compare that substring against `target`:

```
function confirmEnding(str, target) {
    return str.length >= target.length && str.slice(-target.length) === target;
}
```

Re your actual code:

1. `concat` doesn't modify the string you call it on, it *returns* a *new* string (it has to; strings are *immutable* [unchangeable] in JavaScript)
2. If you fix #1, your outer loop just copies `target` to `targetWord` but in reverse order. Your *inner* loop copies `str` to `strWord` in reverse order **repeatedly**, so you'll end up with `target.length` copies of it in `strWord`.
3. Nothing in the function tries to take only *part* of `str` (the last part, with the same length as `target`). You end up comparing the full strings (if you fix #1 and #2), not the substring at the end of `str`.

Finally, just a side note: Any time you find yourself writing:

```
if (a == b) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

you can more concisely and idiomatically write

```
return a == b;
```

which does exactly the same thing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) **returns** the new string.

Use `strWord += whatever;` instead.

Comment: yea i thought about it immediately after posting, before even reading your comment. I mixed up programming languages.

Comment: Interesting, what language were you thinking of?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm not sure, but it's like that in many languages https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586905/how-does-let-var-resolve-mutability

Comment: myself i probably thought about those that don't have `var` at all — Haskell, OCaml, Rust I think